# how to solve firebase Realtime database chat application with separate user data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some working code with firebase realtime database.. but it write all user data in a specific location. problem is all user see the same message. but want to do that every user write their data different location. and get their data only.
here is the write code:

```
    const msg = document.getElementById('message');

function sendMessage(){
    var Msg = msg.value;
    var snt = firebase.database().ref('/messages').push(Msg);
    snt.then(successfull, failed);
}
```

and the read code is:

```
firebase.database().ref('/messages').on('child_added', function(data){
    console.log(data.val());
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    node.innerHTML = data.val();
    document.getElementById('chat').appendChild(node);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to have some sort of user id stored with the message so the messages can be distinguished.

Comment: yes.. look like that

Comment: You need to add a property such as `userid` to the `messages` database structure, so you could store user id.